# Use of the apostrophe in grandparents

Tags: grammaticality

If I had a sentence *I had my own room at my grandparents' place.* I think I would place the apostrophe as shown because I'm talking about both grandmother and grandfather. However, let's say I shorten the sentence to *I had my own room at my grandparents'*. Am I correct in leaving the apostrophe as I have done?

Comment: Terry, what difference could that particular shortening make, please? Would you still be talking about both your grandparents, or  not?

Either way, would you consider asking the same Question somewhere such as English Language Learners, please?

Comment: @RobbieGoodwin In situations where you are limited to a certain number of words, you sometimes need to cut down on the word count without, hopefully, taking away from the meaning. For example, our local newspaper has a 200 word limit on letters to the editor. Let's say I write what I want to say, but I find the word count is 203. At this point I need to eliminate 3 words. Now, are you requesting addressing such questions to English Language Learners rather than here or in addition to here.

Comment: Please be a lot more realistic. Word counts have nothing to do with grandparents or apostrophes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you're correct.

Your second sentence is the first sentence but just not saying the final word.

In cases with unspoken words, the forms of the remaining words generally remain the same as if the unspoken words were there.